# How to have 2 time series data in an excel chart, with different format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Ie. For example I want one time series to be dots, while the other to be a joined line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just draw them both the same then right click on one of them to Format it as you require.